# How do you create global variables without typing `global` in each function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a global variable, but from what I know you need to type "global" in every function.

This example is in Python 2.7:

```
a = 10

def change():
    global a
    a = 2
    print a

def reverse():
    global a
    a = 10
    print a

// Output:
// 2
// 4
```

I'm trying to re-create the code above without the use of `global` for every variable in every function I am going to create. Is there a better way to do this?

To better explain this situation, I have a dictionary and I intend to use many different functions on it. The problem is, I don't really want to be using `function(dict)` or `do_this(dict)` each time, I prefer `function()` or `do_this()`. My thinking is that if `dict` was global, I could solve this problem.

P.S
Thank you for all the answers! Not exactly what I was looking for, but I appreciate the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: The language designers aren't particularly interested in making global variables convenient.

Comment: In general, avoid global variables (especially if you have to use `global`, even just once). Use classes.

Comment: Maybe use a dictionary to store values at the module level.

Comment: Don't use `global`, basically ever. It's bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to read the variable (not modify it), you don't need the `global` line. See the offical [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python). However, if you really want to circumvent this rule, you can make a global dictionary (or list or other mutable data structure) and put your global variables in there. Then you can manipulate them through the global dictionary:

```
a = 4
globs = dict(g1=3)


def print_a():
    print(a)  # not modifying, so you don't need `global`
    globs['g1'] += 1  # technically not modifying globs either.
    print(globs)

print_a() # 4 \n {'g1', 4}
print(globs) # {'g1', 4}
```

Why does this work? (I'm going to explain the best I know here, but please feel free to edit if you know better). Replace "modify" with "reassign" in your head. When you change the value of `a` (`a += 1` for example), you're actually reassigning `a` so Python won't let you. When you're changing a value in `globs`, you're not actually reassigning anything to the name `globs`, so it lets you. A link that may help you:

- http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html will step through what the interpreter is doing.

The thing that you can't do in a function without declaring `global` is to change the arrow from the global namespace to point to something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Globo(object):
    pass


def change():
    Globo.a = 2
    print Globo.a
```

Comment: Your indentation is a bit off ... try this: https://gist.github.com/benhoyt/8d69954e619a5961a37369275d6239c0 :-)

Comment: Thought about same joke, but yours has one argument more. If knows how to use function parameters, what is for the globals?